# DAG Kth shortest path dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

This is not for homework. I am working through a practice test (not graded) in preparation for a final in a couple of weeks. I have no idea where to go with this one.

Let G = (V;E) be a DAG (directed-acyclic-graph) of n vertices and m edges.

Each edge (u; v) of E has a weight w(u; v) that is an arbitrary value (positive, zero, or negative).

Let k be an input positive integer.

A path in G is called a k-link path if the path has no more than k edges. Let s and t be two vertices of G. A k-link shortest path from s to t is defined as a k-link path from s to t that has the minimum total sum of edge weights among all possible k-link s-to-t paths in G.

Design an **O(k(m+ n))** time algorithm to compute a k-link shortest path from s to t.

Any help on the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what shortest path algorithms do you know that handle DAGs with arbitrary weights? I'm pretty sure 99% of CS undergrad curriculums teach precisely one. Could that algorithm help you here?

Comment: Well it was mentioned but nothing anywhere near the runtime that this question requires...

Comment: Hm, why do you say that? What if `k = n`?

Comment: Because the algorithms that have been mentioned have very different run times. I am not sure if k=n would work because then the question would just ask for O(n(m+n))

Comment: What's the algorithm you're thinking of? And my point is that, if we're thinking of the same algorithm, then it has the _correct runtime_. It has a time complexity of `O(n + k(m + n) + k)` which is indeed `O(k(m + n))`. My hint was that you only think it's too slow because you think `k` is some small number... what if you set it to `n`? Then do you see how `O(k(m + n))` can be slow?

Comment: I guess that I have no idea of the algorithm that you are thinking of.

Comment: Which shortest path algorithm do you know for arbitrary weight DAGs?

Comment: Floyd Warshall's, Bellman Ford...

Comment: Or are you thinking of Johnson's algorithm?

Comment: Hm, I guess I forgot more algorithms than I thought. Regardless, why do you think those algorithms have insufficient time complexities? If you let `k = n` and we know `m = O(n^2)` then the problem's upper bound is quite large `O(n*(m + n))`. In particular, Floyd-Warshall and Bellman-Ford are _both_ `O(n*(m+n))`. The issue is if `k < n`. You'll need to adapt one of those algorithms so that if `k < n` then the runtime is still bounded by `O(k*(m+n))`. I'm being intentionally ambiguous since you're studying. If you read and understand those algorithms the answer should be intuitive.

Comment: Hmm ok well my gut says to start with Bellman-Ford.

Comment: @BoredFoo you should learn bellman ford in order to pass the final

Answer (score 2):

Let `dp[amount][currentVertex]` give us the length of the shortest path in G which starts from s, ends at `currentVertex` and consists of `amount` edges.

```
make all values of dp unset
dp[0][s] = 0

for pathLength in (0, 1, .. k-1)             // (1)
    for vertex in V
        if dp[pathLength][vertex] is set     
            for each u where (vertex, u) is in E    // (2), other vertex of the edge
                if dp[pathLength+1][u] is unset or greater than dp[pathLength][vertex] + cost(vertex, u)
                    set dp[pathLength+1][u] = dp[pathLength][vertex] + cost(vertex, u)

best = dp[k][t]
for pathLength in (0, 1, .. k)
    if dp[pathLength][t] < best
        best = dp[pathLength][t]
```

The algorithm above will give you the length of the k-link shortest path from s to t in G. Its time complexity is dominated by the complexity for the loop (1). The loop (1) alone has complecity O(k), while its inner part - (2) simply traverses the graph. If you use an adjacency list, (2) can be implemented in O(n+m). Therefore the overall complexity is O(k*(n+m)).

However, this will give you only the length of the path, and not the path itself. You can modify this algorithm by storing the previous vertex for each value of `dp[][]`. Thus, whenever you set the value of `dp[pathLength+1][u]` with the value of `dp[pathLength][vertex] + cost(vertex, u)` for some variables `vertex`, `u`, `pathLength` you would know that the previous used vertex was `vertex`. Therefore, you would store it like `prev[pathLength+1][u] = vertex`.

After that, you can get the path you want like. The idea is to go backwards by using the links you had created in `prev`:

```
pLen = pathLength such that dp[pathLength][t] is minimal
curVertex = t

path = []           // empty array
while pLen >= 0
    insert curVertex in the beginning of path
    curVertex = prev[pLen][curVertex]
    pLen = pLen - 1
```

`path` is stored the k-link shortest path from s to t in G.

Comment: Few things. The complexity is `O(k(n+m))` with the adjacency list, not `O(n+m)` which matters because `k` is not necessarily `O(1)`. Second, you probably shouldn't use 0 as the sentinel value for unset since the edges can have arbitrary weights (e.g. a shortest `k-link` might have weight 0). Third, typically this algorithm is implemented so that `d[pathLength][u]` is the shortest weight with up to `pathLength` edges; and I believe, in fact, that your implementation already does this. Finally, pretty sure you want to remove the `is set` check. Otherwise this looks about right +1

Comment: So set the sentinel value  to Infinity, yeah?

Comment: @roliu Thanks! 1) fixed, that's what I meant 2) I use 0 only for initializing dp[0][s]. I didn't mention 0 as sentinel value for unset - typically I would use for sentinel some very big value, more than the sum of all edges, or if this is hard, I would introduce another (boolean) array `isSet[][]`. 3) Yes, it depends on the implementation. In mine, I later have to cycle over all values of `pathLength` to find the minimum while in what you suggest it is directly in `dp[k][t]`. The `is set` check again depends on the implementation.

Comment: @yasen Ah I see now how you are using "unset" and that I misread your condition for setting `dp[pathLength+1][u]`. I think this still works... By the way, this is just a variation of Bellman Ford's, @BoredFoo, heh. Notice that the complexity is appropriate, I'm not sure how you convinced yourself that it was "nothing anywhere near".

Comment: @roliu Yes, indeed. It's almost the same as Bellman-Ford, but the outer cycle is up to K, and not |V|-1. This reminds me that we can reduce the memory to only one dimension, as in Bellman-Ford. Anyway, I think it is better in this way.